# rewrite rule to remove a folder from a path and keep rest of directory structure

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, directory, structure

In my base directory I have a lot of folders. I would like to put these folders into a sub-directory.

domain.com/test/test.html

would have the file structure:

domain.com/subdir/test/test.html

and still be at the same url: domain.com/test/

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdir/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Copied from another answer here does that but it also stops other requests to the base directory.

I need it to check for foldername matches in the subdir and if it exists or if not serve from base directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# these conditions are optional, they're to make sure you don't clobber a legit request
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# these conditions aren't optional, they check to see if the requested file/dir exists inside /subdir
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/subdir%{REQUEST_URI} -d

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/$1 [L]
```